# Clicking image with mechanize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping, mechanize

clicking a text `agent.click(page.link_with(:text => 'some_text')` with mechainze is piece of cake. How to click an image with mechanize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather similar. You just need to grab one of the attributes of your image. have a look below..:

`agent.click(page.image_with(:alt=> 'your image')`

Comment: Even if you fixed the missing ) this would still not work because you cannot click an image. @Tanzeeb's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Clicking on a pure HTML image will typically have no effect. If the image has an `onclick` handler, you will not be able to click on it with Mechanize as it does not support javascript.

You may want to use something like Capybara with the Webkit, PhantomJS or Selenium driver instead.